# diccionarios/lista de compras

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, funciones, diccionarios

Desde ya gracias a todo el que mira este ejercicio.
Estoy trabado en un varias cuestiones. Estoy hace poco iniciándome en programación.
Estoy con diccionarios.
Tengo una lista de   diccionario llamado boletas

```
boletas = [{'fecha_compra' : '29-05-22','precio' : 12000,'productos' : {'Chocolate': 1,'Mantequilla': 1,'Huevos': 12,'Pan' : 1}},{'fecha_compra' : '31-05-22':2400,'productos' : {'Pan': 1, 'Leche' : 2} },{'fecha_compra' : '01-06-22','precio' : 3000,'productos' : {'Mantequilla': 2, 'Azucar' : 1}}]
```

Tengo que  crear una función `precio_mes(boletas)` y retornar un diccionario `{'05-22' : 14400,'06-22' : 3000,}...`

Esto es lo que yo intente hacer... pero mi resultado luego de ir identificando la llave y su value ....pero me quedan 3 diccionarios y no se como unificar sumar los gastos de un mismo mes....

```
for k in boletas: 
    fechas_a_saber= k[('fecha_compra')]
    plata_gastada_este_mes= k[('precio')]
    los_datos_que_quiero=fechas_a_saber[3:] ,plata_gastada_este_mes
    nuevo_dict = dict(zip(los_datos_que_quiero[0:], los_datos_que_quiero[1:])) 
    print(nuevo_dict)
```

Comment: necesito orientación ...gracias .

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Le dí formato a tu código, pero está todo en una línea. Quizás el interprete pueda con eso, pero sería mejor si lo públicas en varias líneas y con la indentación normal. Dale a [edit] tu pregunta para eso. Saludos.

Comment: gracias!.Si , todavía no entiendo como es...cuando  pongo el mensaje con el codigo ... y me cuerta que me deje mandarlo porque me marca errores que no se como arreglar y por ahi termino mandando un mensaje que es poco claro .. gracias

Comment: en tu pregunta dices: "Tengo que crear una función `precio_mes(boletas)` y retornar un diccionario"  pero en tu codigo no tienes ninguna function y no retornas nada.

Comment: Hola . Gracias por el comentario... no se si esta bien ... normalmente cuando empiezo a hacer el codigo ...pongo la lista y voy resolviendolo y cuando lo tengo ...ahi agrego el def... y el return final ... no se si es practico ...Abierto a algún concejo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

de lo que alcanzo a ver, me parece que lo que esta pasando es que se estan definiendo tres diccionarios en vez de acumularlos en uno solo:

- Codigo previo:

```
for k in boletas: #quite los () en fechas y plata para simplicar
    fechas_a_saber = k['fecha_compra'] #fechas_a_saber = k[('fecha_compra')]
    plata_gastada_este_mes = k['precio']  #plata_gastada_este_mes = k[('precio')]
    los_datos_que_quiero = fechas_a_saber[3:]
    nuevo_dict = dict(                  # <---- aqui se define un nuevo dict pero
        zip(                            # pero no se almazena en ninguna lado   
             los_datos_que_quiero[0:], 
             los_datos_que_quiero[1:]
             )
         )
```

- Propuesta:

```
nuevo_dict = {}

for k in boletas:
    fechas_a_saber = k['fecha_compra'] #fechas_a_saber = k[('fecha_compra')]
    plata_gastada_este_mes = k['precio']  #plata_gastada_este_mes = k[('precio')]
    los_datos_que_quiero = fechas_a_saber[3:]
    
    if los_datos_que_quiero not in nuevo_dict:
        nuevo_dict[los_datos_que_quiero] = plata_gastada_este_mes
    else:
        nuevo_dict[los_datos_que_quiero] += plata_gastada_este_mes
```

Interpretacion completa:

```
boletas = [
    {
     'fecha_compra' : '29-05-22',
     'precio' : 12000,
     'productos' : {'Chocolate': 1,'Mantequilla': 1,'Huevos': 12,'Pan' : 1}
     },
    {
     # 'fecha_compra' : '31-05-22':2400, #Me parece que aqui hay un typo y falta precio
     'fecha_compra' : '31-05-22',
     'precio':2400,
     'productos' : {'Pan': 1, 'Leche' : 2} 
     },
    {
     'fecha_compra' : '01-06-22',
     'precio' : 3000,
     'productos' : {'Mantequilla': 2, 'Azucar' : 1}
     }
    ]


nuevo_dict = {}

for k in boletas:
    fechas_a_saber = k['fecha_compra'] #fechas_a_saber = k[('fecha_compra')]
    plata_gastada_este_mes = k['precio']  #plata_gastada_este_mes = k[('precio')]
    los_datos_que_quiero = fechas_a_saber[3:]
    
    if los_datos_que_quiero not in nuevo_dict:
        nuevo_dict[los_datos_que_quiero] = plata_gastada_este_mes
    else:
        nuevo_dict[los_datos_que_quiero] += plata_gastada_este_mes
        
print(nuevo_dict)
```

Comment: Genial ...voy a probar por este camino .

Comment: tu corrección respecto a que falta 'precio' es correcta! gracias